# What's the best method to transfer strings from wordpress plugin to server?

Tags: wordpress

Good day.

I have my own WordPress plugin in which I want to deliver certain things (configuration) to my webserver.

The plugin will be available for free afterwards and I would like to send certain values from the plugin to my webserver when activating the plugin (only with the permission of the user).

What is the best way to transfer values ​​like (plugin configuration, name, email etc.) from a WordPress Plugin to a PHP Webserver?

I would have done it first with curl but that could be disabled, right?

I'm looking for a simple way to pass parameters (strings/arrays only) from a client (plugin) to my host (webserver).

It is important that it is not cURL or fopen, etc., so a function which can be disabled. It should always work to 100%.

Would $_GET be a good option? Is it only usable within a form or? So the user must submit a form to transfer the values.

What else is there to do with a pure PHP Server - Client | Client - Server connection?

Comment: You can setup an api endpoint on your php server to accept incoming requests from your plugin. 

See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_post

You can send a post request in your plugin to your php server.

Note: You can trigger the action in your plugin wherever you want. It may be when a form is submitted, but you can place code to run the api post request wherever you like. 

This isn't the full solution, but it should help point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks! Looks really good. :)